# Why does println() function behave differently in this situation?

Tags: java

Here the `"Area is"` part in the main does not come first onto the output stream. Why is it so ? Is there a way to go around this issue ?

```java
class Rectangle {

    double dim1;
    double dim2;

    Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        dim1 = a;
        dim2 = b;
    }

    double area() {
        System.out.println("Inside Area for Rectangle.");
        return dim1 * dim2;
    }
}

class FindAreas {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rectangle R = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        System.out.println("Area is " + R.area());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: first executes `R.area()`, then `System.out.println("Area is " + R.area());`. Why should it be an issue?

Comment: Order of execution: first the call to `area()` is evaluted (in which the 1st `println(...)` is exexcuted). Then, the result of this call si concatenated with `"area is "` and passed along to the 2nd `println(...)` call.

Comment: The order of execution of statements does **not** follow the order of appearance in your code file. I down voted because
[No debugging](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: shouldn't the "Area is" part be printed first...i've come from c and i'm new to object oriented programming

Comment: `R.area()` is a part of output. it should be calculated **first**

Comment: When `R.area()` is called `println("Inside Area...")` statement is executed first and then the calculations and then the value is returned to `println("Area is"..)` statement, then it finishes preparing string value to output and then `"Area is <somevalue>"` value is printed

Answer (score 4):

Because you pass a single `String` to `System.out.println` and constructing that `String` requires invoking the method. That is, your current code can be thought of like

```
String t = new StringBuilder("Area is ").append(R.area()).toString();
System.out.println(t);
```

You can change your approach, and get the output you seem to expect, by modifying the code from a single `print` in `main` into two. Like:

```
System.out.print("Area is ");
System.out.println(R.area());
```

Outputs:

```
Area is Inside Area for Rectangle.
200.0
```

Comment: While your suggestion works the explanation why is wrong...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `System.out.println("Area is " + R.area());` passes one `String` to `System.out.println`, to construct that `String` requires invoking `R.area()`. Where am I wrong? `new StringBuilder("Area is ").append(R.area()).toString()`

Comment: The real raeson is that the TO calls `System.out.println()` **twice** and the **order of the calls** is not what the TO expects.

Comment: The fundamental design problem is embedding print statements in a method whose responsibility seems to be to **calculate** something.    ,